# React widgets within text (static HTML)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a book with a bunch of small interactive widgets within the text content. So I have text like this in my database:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>

<div class="interactive-graph" />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>
```

These widgets require JS to run. Some of them are re-used in other chapters of the book, but most of them are one-offs.

I understand that React requires a single root component, and I've used React to make web apps before. But I don't understand how I would be able to write these widgets as React components and automatically mount them as the dynamic text is rendered on the page.

Is React just a bad fit for this? Can you think of any examples that demonstrate how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is perfectly suitable for React.

Simplest example that would work for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello React!</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>

  <div id="interactive-graph" />
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>

  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('interactive-graph') );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Example was taken from [React Getting started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html). But generally, you want to introduce build system that converts your JSX files into JS bundle by using browserify or wabpack and include it into your main HTML that way. That requires some initial learning curve. Mentioned link is the best place to start.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks so much. This makes sense!